# Assign data to Vue instance after axios.all()

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am calling two requests with `axios.all()` on `mounted()` and I can not assign the response data to my Vue data.
I have included some `console.log()` in order to understand what is going on.

```
app = new Vue({
    data: {
        countries: [],
        cities: [],
    },
    methods: {
        getCountries() {
            return axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/utils/countries/',
            })
        },
        getCities() {
            return axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/utils/cities/',
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('1 ' + this.cities)
        axios.all([this.getCountries(), this.getCities()])
        .then(axios.spread(function (countries, cities) {
            this.countries = countries.data;
            this.cities = cities.data;
            console.log('2 ' + this.cities)
        }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
        console.log('3 ' + this.cities)
    }
});
```

Ouput :

```
1
3
2 [object Object]...
```

My call is successful but `this.cities`and `this.countries` remains empty. 
How can I pass them my response data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword inside your Axios callback probably refers to the lexical context of its own function. Because of this, you're assigning to a `cities` and `countries` property on the wrong object. Which is why those properties remain empty on your Vue component.

By using an arrow function, `this` will be bound to the enclosing lexical context, which is in this case, your Vue component.

Try this:

```
.then(axios.spread((countries, cities) => {
    this.countries = countries.data;
    this.cities = cities.data;
}))
```